# RewriteRule not redirect properly

Tags: php, redirect

I am formating the redirect of my site URL using this.
I got a problem on redirecting properly.

CASE 1:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9_-]*)$  user/profile.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-z0-9_-]*)$  user/profile.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
```

The code is alright when accessing the profile page, the actual url is (user/profile.php)

```
http://thisismysite.com/1234567
```

however I can't access the main index, it is still redirect to (user/profile.php)

http://thisismysite.com

CASE 2:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9_-]*)$/  user/profile.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-z0-9_-]*)$  user/profile.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
```

in this case, I can access the main index and the profile but I need to add '/' at the end

```
http://thisismysite.com/1234567/
```

But I don't want the backslash to appear at the end?

What should I do?
Thanks

Comment: you should really use a router script instead of hacking the htaccess. and then you can rely on a simple FallbackResource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For case 1 replace `*` with `+` so your rule looks like this:

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9_-]+)$  user/profile.php?id=$1 [L,NC]`

That should take care of being able to see the index but still redirecting to the user profiles when you have a profile url.

Comment: No problem. If this was the solution to your question mark it as the right answer for future reference.

Comment: yup I will, I just need more minutes for me to be able to mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

For add `/` at the end

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9_-]*)/$  user/profile.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```